# Make a UIImage from a MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to create a `UIImage` from a `MKMapView`. My map is correctly displayed in the view, however the `UIImage` produced is just a gray image. Here's the relevant snippet.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.bounds.size);
[mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Anyone know how to make a `UIImage` using MapKit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using the same code that is tested with ios sdk 4.1 and works fine. So, when map is already displayed to user and user press the button this action will be called:

```
UIImage *image = [mapView renderToImage];
```

and here is the wrapper function realized as UIView extension:

```
- (UIImage*) renderToImage
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
  [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
  return image;
}
```

So, the problem is not in that code part.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS7, there is a new API on MapKit for this called MKMapSnapshotter. So you actually don't need to create a mapview, load the tiles and create a graphic context capturing yourself.

Take a look into it at  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is the improved function for retina display:

```
@implementation UIView (Ext)
- (UIImage*) renderToImage
{
  // IMPORTANT: using weak link on UIKit
  if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
  } else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
  }

 [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
 return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Loren. There are multiple layers in the mapView. I think the first one is the map and the second on is the google layer. They might have changed something in the mapkit after 3.1. You can try

```
[[[mapView.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:1] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

You can also try

```
CGRect rect = [mapView bounds];
CGImageRef mapImage = [mapView createSnapshotWithRect:rect];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, mapView may not finish load so image may be grey.
as

```
mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:
```

will not always be called, you should get UIImage in

```
mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:fullyRendered:
```

so, the code just like this

```
- (UIImage *)renderToImage:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.bounds.size);
  [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this immediately after initializing the map (maybe in viewDidLoad?), you could get a gray image as the map is not finished drawing yet.

Try:

- Calling the capture code using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: using a short delay (even 0 seconds might work so it fires right after the current method is finished)
- If you are adding annotations, call the capture code in the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method

**Edit:**
On the simulator, using performSelector, a zero delay works.  On the device, a longer delay is required (about 5 seconds).

However, if you add annotations (and you capture in the didAddAnnotationViews method), it works immediately on both the simulator and device.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I wait for the map to load, it is in the view and looks ok.

Comment: This has worked for me (also on 4.1).  Have you tried calling the capture with a button press to see if it is a timing issue or something else?