# Is it permitted to take a ''screenshot'' of an MKMapView and allow users to post to twitter, facebook, etc. ? (iPhone / iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, uiimage, mkmapview

I'm trying to get some clarity on whether or not Google permits the use of screenshots of the `MKMapView` to be used elsewhere. I have looked around and found the following way of creating a `UIImage` from the `MKMapView` which is detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159596/make-a-uiimage-from-a-mkmapview).

My concern is that Google will kick up a fuss about it or that Apple will reject the app if I make use of this code to create the `UIImage` with the intent of allowing users to post it to Facebook, Twitter and other social networking sites.

I have also had a look around online and found Google's [terms of use policy](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html) for Google Maps, however I'm still unclear on whether or not it's permissible.

Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is forbidden by Term 10.1 of the [iPhone terms](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html) (equivalent to 10.1.1(a) in the [General Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)):

> You must not
>   10.1 access or use the Service or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service, or through other explicitly authorized means Google may designate;

"Content" includes map imagery, and a `UIImage` is not provided in the Service nor is it explicitly authorised.

The correct way of producing an image is with the Static Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Term 10.3, it might be ok if it's to improve the performances, but i guess you will have to keep the image in RAM.

> 10.3 pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;